# Need an datepicker in query like Hotel websites use in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need help as I'm trying to create a bookings system like http://www.strandpalacehotel.co.uk/ however I don't have the knowledge to code one from scratch so does anyone know where I can find a plugin?

I need:
-Date From
-Date To
-Nights (to update with Dates)
-Adults

All I can find are date pickers but nothing that auto updates the Nights field. Please help!!

Comment: So... you want to find [the difference of two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41948/901048)?

Comment: I'd start by looking at jQuery UI datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Basicly the exact same thing as  http://www.strandpalacehotel.co.uk/ two datepiackers and a 'Nights' option that updates the datepickers. Thats the bit I'm finding difficult

Comment: In face i just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263482/jquery-ui-datepicker-using-2-date-fields-trying-to-get-date-difference and this shows exactly what I want except I want the nights field to be a <select> field and I want the dates to already be in the <input> fields

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has a pretty ubiquitous datepicker (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). Lots of other widgets in there that you might find useful, too.

Comment: Yeah I can make the datepicker work however I want to have another option field with "Number of Nights" that updates if two chosen dates have been selected. Also vice-versa if number of nights is selected the datepicker updates itself.